Scheduled jobs failing after 5.80.1 upgrade
I set up a weekly scheduled job to run a report. It was working fine until I updated to 5.80.1 from 5.78.x. If I execute the job manually from the web UI it works fine. When it's run via schedule (either using the cv, which worked fine before, or wp-cli as an attempt to see if maybe the latest cv also needs an update, command in cron), it fails with:
Finished execution of Weekly Nametag Report with result: Failure, Error message: Report Mail Triggered...
Did not find a valid instance to execute
I've also noticed that the failure message API list is
a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}
while the working log entry has:
a:4:{s:7:"version";i:3;s:10:"instanceId";s:2:"42";s:6:"format";s:3:"csv";s:8:"sendmail";s:1:"1";}
The scheduled job config hasn't changed, and still seems to be what the docs suggest it should be:

Haven't found anything in the release notes that gives me any clue as to why this isn't working any more.
What silly thing have I missed?
Thanks...

You can apply this change or wait for 5.81 next week https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/31624/files
diff --git a/CRM/Core/JobManager.php b/CRM/Core/JobManager.php
index 3d5ff0d8293..96ff3fada78 100644
--- a/CRM/Core/JobManager.php
+++ b/CRM/Core/JobManager.php
@@ -90,7 +90,7 @@ public function execute($auth = TRUE) {
     $jobs = array_merge($successfulJobs, $maybeUnsuccessfulJobs);
     foreach ($jobs as $job) {
       $temp = ['class' => NULL, 'parameters' => NULL, 'last_run' => NULL];
-      $scheduledJobParams = array_merge($job, $temp);
+      $scheduledJobParams = array_merge($temp, $job);
       $jobDAO = new CRM_Core_ScheduledJob($scheduledJobParams);
 
       if ($jobDAO->needsRunning()) {


Yeah, that’d do it. Thanks, patch works.

Thanks. Patch worked for me too. Jobs broke for me also after upgrading to 5.80.1.
